# Can I use USB C 3.2 Gen2 connector for power and data for a medical application?

Tags: emc, usb-c, brushed-dc-motor, medical

My class 3 medical system uses 36V (~100W), 100Mbps ethernet for communication. I am planning to use USB 3.2 gen2 connector and cables to simplify my cabling in the system, and to have EMC shielding end to end.

I will use these connectors only as a medium, will not use as actual USB, like power negotiation etc.

1. Can I use off the shelf shielded cables, if I just use as a medium not power negotiation?
2. I believe the standard cable will have some power ICs closer to the connectors.  Will it impact me if I use only as a medium?
3. Do USB3.2 meet 60601-1 & 2 medical, safety and EMC standards or do I need to take care anything?
4. If it doesn't meet medical standard, is there any other shielded simple connector I can use?

Comment: You basically want to use a standard like USB 3.2 gen2 in a non-standard way for a real sellable (medical) product? I don't think that this is a good idea.

Comment: "_I will use these connectors only as a medium, will not use as actual USB.. like power negotiation etc.._" - this sounds incredibly concerning (possibly dangerous), given the application you have in mind...

Comment: what does [tag:brushed-dc-motor] have to do with your question?

Comment: My system has brushed DC motors, which uses 36V..thats why added that keyword Marcus

Comment: @NICEGUYNICEGUY then you *must* explain that in your question text when using that tag. I mean, maybe your system also has resistors, but you don't tag them…

Comment: I think the question is very clear and on-point. Just because the solution it suggests is bad doesn't mean it's a bad question. I've upvoted. Someone else surely will have similarly creative ideas, and downvoting this question will potentially prevent them from getting clear answers as to why doing as the question suggests is a terrible idea.

Comment: "Medical application" could be anything from a battery charger in some waiting room to a pacemaker. It depends on how critical your application is and what the requirements are. Ethernet in general for example is unsuitable for safety-critical applications.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the standards and laws in that area, but:

Medical devices often require proper galvanic separation, which typically is provided by the transformers in Ethernet. That alone might make migrating to the capacitor-coupled USB3 signalling impossible.

> and to have EMC shielding end to end.

hm, I don't really see how USB improves over shielded ethernet cables there?

> I believe the standard cable will have some power ICs closer to the connectors, will it impact me if I use only as a medium?

A standard USB 2 cable is passive thing, no IC. (USB2 would suffice for 100 Mb/s).

USB3 SuperSpeed and faster cables are forced to have an identification IC built in. ([spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%202.3%20Release%20202310.zip), Table 3-1.)

> Do USB3.2 meets 60601-1 & 2 medical, safety and emc standards? or do I need to take care anything?

USB is not concerned with safety aspects at all. And, EMC standards concern whole devices, not interface standards, so this question is ill-formed. "Does 98 octane gasoline meet inner city maximum speed car regulations?" makes about as much sense.

> If it doesn't meet medical standard, any other shielded simple connector I can use?

Again, I'm not sure which standard you're under. "Medical device" isn't specific enough! But, as said, at least in Europe, for some medical device types that connect to a patient's body to some device attached to the power grid, even indirectly, you'll need an isolation that makes shielded cabling that is connected to enclosures on both end impossible.

Anyways, you asking us here has very little point – your device needs to fulfill the specific regulations of *your* country (unspecified) for *your* type of medical device (unspecified) under *your* conditions (unspecified). You will have to find someone who's both familiar with your type of device and the applicable standards and laws, otherwise you won't be able to get your device certified. This is typically a contractor's market.

Comment: Aren't all USB3 capable cables required to have an e-marker chip on the CC line? https://www.bytecable.com/what-is-the-e-marker-chip/ Which would make using the CC line for anything else risky.

Comment: … @user1937198 literally the fourth sentence on the page you link to. No, they don't.

Comment: Its says not all USB-C cables do, but one of the criteria for those that do is 'Support USB3.0 or higher transmission speed' The table specifically says that only 3A only USB2 only cables aren't expected to have a marker.

Comment: @user1937198 you're right, my apologies; usb.org's specification *USB Type-C Cable and Connector Specification* disagrees with my memory and agrees with you and the link. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use off the shelf shielded cables, if I just use as a medium, not power negotiation?

No, because the first person out there will plug an actual USB-C device or power source into your system and very bad things will happen (smoke).

> I believe the standard cable will have some power ICs closer to the connectors, will it impact me if I use only as a medium?

Those are the optional cable identification ICs, and there can also be redriver ICs. You'll blow them up. There can be compliant USB 3.2 cables that are active and not passive, with data redrivers. They won't work for Ethernet at all.

> Do USB3.2 meets 60601-1 & 2 medical, safety and emc standards? or do I need to take care anything?

Apples and oranges. Can a USB3.2 implementation meet those standards? Yes. Does any particular implementation do? Well, does any particular phone with a USB-C connector on it comply with those standards? That's your answer. *Generally not at all*, in case it wasn't clear.

> If it doesn't meet medical standard, any other shielded simple connector I can use?

Yes. A shielded Cat 6 cable. That's what they are for: better EMC than unshielded ones.